# How can I make a table with 2 column on top and 3 column below. I have tried so many times, tried to look for online tutorials but cannot find any

Tags: html, html-table

I want to make a table with 2 column at first and 3 column in the second row. The problem is, I cannot adjust them to my desired layout. I'm sorry if my question is hard to understand. I've attached a picture link for your reference.

```css
table, td { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Table that I want to make]

the above picture is what I want.

Comment: Do you have any other requirements about the width of the cells/columns? In the second row, it should be a simple 1-col-width, 2-col-width, 1-col-width combination (so the two cells in the middle are merged).

Comment: Well, you have four columns in the table; it seems like you want six. On the top and bottom rows, span three columns for each cell, in the middle, span two.

Comment: Might I suggest that this doesn't look like a layout for tabular data (though if you have representative content to show that may well change my mind), so I'd argue that using a CSS grid is probably a better idea, again though: this does depend on the content. There is - as Heretic Monkey notes - a simple way of achieving this with `colspan` attributes, but if you do reconsider the use of the `<table>`, then there's also a way with CSS Grid: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5psL1txj/).

Comment: Thank you all so much. I really thought I'll get all those replies after some few days from the day I post, but here it is!!. So much appreciated to all of you for the genuine HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That configuration is impossible using `colspan` unless there was a value of 1.5 for the top and bottom rows. But there is a way by nesting a `<table>` within a `<td colspan='2'>` in the middle row. Also, it's valid HTML.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
}

table table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

table table td {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan='2' style='border: 0'>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Or, without using nested `<table>` elements: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5psL1txj/)?

Comment: Sure that'll work, but I suggested a nested `<table>` so it can have tabular data that'll line-up to `<th>` properly if needed.

Comment: thank you so much @zer00ne for your help. You didn't take it as a silly question but shared your skills on that. Thankyou so much. So much appreciated for this.

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas. I am new to CSS and your code gave me a boost to really study them thoroughly. Peace